# jquery - Export table to Excel

Tags: jquery, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I try to export my table to *Csv* Or *Excel* file. Content of header & body in my table is Persian.

> "روز"

this is my code:

```
function bestWayToExport() {
    var table = document.getElementById('tableCount');
    var html = table.outerHTML;
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel;UTF-8,' + escape(html));
}
```

Now, result is **incorrect**.

> " %u0631%u0648%u0632 "

What to do?! (Please No **NEGATIVE -** to me!)

Answer (score 1):

Hi i found below code may help you to what you want

```js
$("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#dvData').html());
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
body {
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: Calibri;
    padding : 10px;
}
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color:grey;
    color: white;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
input {
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: Calibri;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btnExport" value=" Export Table data into Excel " />
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="dvData">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Column One</th>
            <th>Column Two</th>
            <th>Column Three</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row1 Col1</td>
            <td>row1 Col2</td>
            <td>row1 Col3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row2 Col1</td>
            <td>row2 Col2</td>
            <td>row2 Col3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row3 Col1</td>
            <td>row3 Col2</td>
            <td><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/">http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

reference

http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/jWAJ7/light/

Comment: Result is **INCORRECT** :  Ø³Ù„Ù„Ù„Ù„Ù„Ù„

Comment: hi, dude it may the problem when you save your html page just try to save only html page and view it this will show **Ø³Ù„Ù„Ù„Ù„Ù„Ù„**  so if u solve this you will be solve that Too...

Comment: just save this html and open in browser does persian characters shown in browser.?

Comment: if not then save html page by encoding UTF-8

Comment: I save this table and open that, but text is : Ø³Ù„Ù„Ù„Ù„Ù„Ù„

Comment: you can encode it with UTF-8 while saving then you can see your language in html

Comment: which tool you use to save html .?
Ohh dude i am saying that you have created the table data in somewhere html right.??? so save that html page ( which includes the your table data in html ) with encoding first

Comment: No tool use. i use jquery to save.

Comment: I haven't tool. ok? I save my table with jquery code, above.